# Run npm run build command on multiple cores

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, virtual-machine

i have a virtual machine (Ubuntu 14.04, 4 cores, one thread per core) with node.js. Now after starting "npm run build" command fully used only one core. Can i run build process of node.js project on multiple cores on this virtual server? Build process is slow. How i can minimize build time?

Can i use doc described below to configure multicore build of project?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster

Thanks!